# How to survive a Jaculas (javelin snake) attack?

Tags: internal-consistency, survival, mythical-creatures

So if you were running through a forest and stumbled into a nest of Jaculi? Jaculuses? They are up in the trees around you and they start flinging themselves at you, trying to pierce through your flesh. All you are carrying is a bag of 1 days rations and a bow, but you weren't prepared and you don't have the bow ready. There is another person running alongside you with nothing. Is there any way to protect both of these people from a Jaculas attack? Thanks!

Comment: With some quick googling, the best I've found from several sources is that it kills via the impact, not via venom.  I've found absolutely nothing describing its size or shape, which would be important in determining the speed at which it impacts and therefore how feasible dodging would be.  Do you have any sources to share?

Comment: Threaten to quit playing if the DM is going to be like that at the start of the first session? I'm not sure how two unarmored people could survive a rain of javelins.

Comment: I mean they *are* mythical creatures, so I'm not sure of an exact size but assume enough force to penetrate a human skull.

Comment: whats wrong with using your pack as a shield?  but really this question needs a lot of information th be answerable, like how you Jaculi work, most people won't even know what they are much less their mythology and abilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remain motionless. The jaculus is not able to spot prey which is not moving. Most people don't know this, they panic and run which is absolutely the worst thing to do. The second worst is trying to fight.

Play statues and wait until other prey presents itself, or darkness falls and you can slip away veeeeeery slowly and quietly.

I love that you call this "reality check".

Answer (score 0):

Dropbears from australia use similar attacks.

[image: Dropbear, terror from above]

So vegemite behind the ears really quick!

Out of vegemite? Grab some bushes and cover your head! They won't attack you if you are camouflaged.

Comment: Sorry what? Not terribly helpful at all considering we don't have vegemite and they will know where you are if you're camo'd.